# How to detect if an app is updated or freshly installed in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have an app on the Windows Phone store and i want to update the app. I want to include a function in to the app to detect if the app is updated from a previous version or it is freshly installed to give specific user experience according to the situation. Is there a way to detect whether the app is updated to freshly installed? I've searched but didn't found any promising material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a workaround, but you could create a file in your Isolated Storage that stores the last version number of the app. Since this file wouldn't get overwritten on update, you could read it when you update to check what the version they're updating from was. If the file doesn't exist, then that means they had the first version of the app.

Comment: Wasn't exactly what i looked for. I need to do it for already existing app on the market. This works for a new app. But this gave me the idea to use a old file that will not be used in the update. if its there that mean it's updated ryt :) thanks for the answer.. that was a kick in the right direction :D

Comment: @KasunKV I know that your app is already in the market. That's why I included my last sentence to check that if the file doesn't exist yet, then the user is using one of the versions previous to the upcoming one :)